# Display single record from ListView / ListAdapter from sql database

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I do a bit of travelling and I wanted to create an app that allowed me to save taxi bookings into a database.  I have only added a few fields to give me an idea how this all works.  I'm quite new to programming and followed a number of tutorials to create an app that allows me to take a csv file and upload it to the app database.  This works well and I have no problems displaying the data.

I managed to get it to both use Toast and alert to bring up windows with data in, but only 6 fields...  I need to have all 16 showing...
I have made some ground on this but still having the Application termination problems when I click on the list items.

I have tried to make an Intent to call the new view results table by new intent in TaxiDetails. no joy...  All help appreciated.
Code as below - All help appreciated and thanks in advance....

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.stravides.jdw;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    TextView lbl;
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    Button btnimport;
    Button btnphone;
    Button btnclear;

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
    public static final int requestcode = 1;
    final Context context = this;

    protected Cursor kursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.stravides.jdw.TaxiDetails.class");
            Cursor kursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
            intent.putExtra("TAXI_ID", kursor.getInt(kursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtresulttext);
        btnimport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        btnphone =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnphone);
        btnclear =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnclear);
        lv = getListView();


        btnimport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    lbl.setText("No activity that can handle file selection. Showing alternatives.");
                }

            }
        });

        btnclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
                    String tableName = "taxiinfo";
                    db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);
                    myList = controller.getAllProducts();
                    if (myList.size() == 0) {
                        ListView lv = getListView();
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,R.layout.v, new String[]
                                {"bID", "bDate", "bTime", "bFrom", "bTo","bFlightNum", "bFlightDest", "bPassenger", "bEmail", "bTelno", "bMobNo", "bCostCentre", "bPersNo", "bCombine", "bNumPass", "bRemarks"}, new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0});
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        lbl.setText("Data Cleared");
                    }
                }
            });

        btnphone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uri = "tel:" + "0031251491418";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

            myList= controller.getAllProducts();
            if (myList.size() != 0) {
                ListView lv = getListView();
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,
                        R.layout.v, new String[]{"bID", "bDate", "bTime", "bFrom", "bTo","bFlightNum", "bFlightDest", "bPassenger", "bEmail", "bTelno", "bMobNo", "bCostCentre", "bPersNo", "bCombine", "bNumPass", "bRemarks"}, new int[]{
                        R.id.txttaxibID, R.id.txttaxibDate, R.id.txttaxibTime,R.id.txttaxibFrom, R.id.txttaxibTo, R.id.txttaxibFlightNum, R.id.txttaxibFlightDest, R.id.txttaxibPassenger, R.id.txttaxibEmail, R.id.txttaxibTelno, R.id.txttaxibMobNo, R.id.txttaxibCostCentre, R.id.txttaxibPersNo, R.id.txttaxibCombine, R.id.txttaxibNumPass, R.id.txttaxibRemarks});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                lbl.setText("");
            }

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
        }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null)
            return;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case requestcode:
                String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
                controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
                String tableName = "taxiinfo";
                db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);
                try {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            FileReader file = new FileReader(filepath);
                            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            String line = "";
                            db.beginTransaction();
                            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                                String[] str = line.split(",", 16);
                                String bID = str[0];
                                String bDate = str[1];
                                String bTime = str[2];
                                String bFrom = str[3];
                                String bTo = str[4];
                                String bFlightNum = str[5];
                                String bFlightDest = str[6];
                                String bPassenger = str[7];
                                String bEmail = str[8];
                                String bTelno = str[9];
                                String bMobNo = str[10];
                                String bCostCentre = str[11];
                                String bPersNo = str[12];
                                String bCombine = str[13];
                                String bNumPass = str[14];
                                String bRemarks = str[15];
                                contentValues.put("bID", bID);
                                contentValues.put("bDate", bDate);
                                contentValues.put("bTime", bTime);
                                contentValues.put("bFrom", bFrom);
                                contentValues.put("bTo", bTo);
                                contentValues.put("bFlightNum", bFlightNum);
                                contentValues.put("bFlightDest", bFlightDest);
                                contentValues.put("bPassenger", bPassenger);
                                contentValues.put("bEmail", bEmail);
                                contentValues.put("bTelno", bTelno);
                                contentValues.put("bMobNo", bMobNo);
                                contentValues.put("bCostCentre", bCostCentre);
                                contentValues.put("bPersNo", bPersNo);
                                contentValues.put("bCombine", bCombine);
                                contentValues.put("bNumPass", bNumPass);
                                contentValues.put("bRemarks", bRemarks);
                                db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
                                lbl.setText("Successfully Updated Database.");
                            }
                            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            db.endTransaction();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            if (db.inTransaction())
                                db.endTransaction();
                            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                            d.setTitle(e.getMessage().toString() + "first");
                            d.show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (db.inTransaction())
                            db.endTransaction();
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Only CSV files allowed");
                        d.show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (db.inTransaction())
                        db.endTransaction();
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle(ex.getMessage().toString() + "second");
                    d.show();
                }
        }

        myList= controller.getAllProducts();
        if (myList.size() != 0) {
            ListView lv = getListView();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,
                    R.layout.v, new String[]{"bID", "bDate", "bTime", "bFrom", "bTo","bFlightNum", "bFlightDest", "bPassenger", "bEmail", "bTelno", "bMobNo", "bCostCentre", "bPersNo", "bCombine", "bNumPass", "bRemarks"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.txttaxibID, R.id.txttaxibDate, R.id.txttaxibTime,R.id.txttaxibFrom, R.id.txttaxibTo, R.id.txttaxibFlightNum, R.id.txttaxibFlightDest, R.id.txttaxibPassenger, R.id.txttaxibEmail, R.id.txttaxibTelno, R.id.txttaxibMobNo, R.id.txttaxibCostCentre, R.id.txttaxibPersNo, R.id.txttaxibCombine, R.id.txttaxibNumPass, R.id.txttaxibRemarks});
        }
    }
}
```

**DBController.java**

```
package com.stravides.jdw;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
        import android.util.Log;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;

public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "jdwtaxi.db", null, 1);  // creating DATABASE
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taxiinfo ( Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bID TEXT,bDate TEXT, bTime TEXT,bFrom TEXT, bTo TEXT, bFlightNum TEXT, bFlightDest TEXT, bPassenger TEXT, bEmail TEXT, bTelno TEXT, bMobNo TEXT, bCostCentre TEXT, bPersNo TEXT, bCombine TEXT, bNumPass TEXT, bRemarks TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old,int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS taxiinfo";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }


    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllProducts() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taxiList;
        taxiList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM taxiinfo";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //Id, Company,Name,Price
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Id", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("bID", cursor.getString(1));
                map.put("bDate", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("bTime", cursor.getString(3));
                map.put("bFrom", cursor.getString(4));
                map.put("bTo", cursor.getString(5));
                map.put("bFlightNum", cursor.getString(6));
                map.put("bFlightDest", cursor.getString(7));
                map.put("bPassenger", cursor.getString(8));
                map.put("bEmail", cursor.getString(9));
                map.put("bTelno", cursor.getString(10));
                map.put("bMobNo", cursor.getString(11));
                map.put("bCostCentre", cursor.getString(12));
                map.put("bPersNo", cursor.getString(13));
                map.put("bCombine", cursor.getString(14));
                map.put("bNumPass", cursor.getString(15));
                map.put("bRemarks", cursor.getString(16));
                taxiList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return taxiList;
    }

}
```

**TaxiDetails.java**

```
package com.stravides.jdw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Ken on 09/08/2015.
 */
public class TaxiDetails extends Activity {

    protected TextView bID;
    protected TextView bDate;
    protected TextView bTime;
    protected TextView bFrom;
    protected TextView bTo;
    protected TextView bFlightNum;
    protected TextView bFlightDest;
    protected TextView bPassenger;
    protected TextView bEmail;
    protected TextView bTelno;
    protected TextView bMobNo;
    protected TextView bCostCentre;
    protected TextView bPersNo;
    protected TextView bCombine;
    protected TextView bNumPass;
    protected TextView bRemarks;
    protected int taxiPos;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.resultstable);

            taxiPos = getIntent().getIntExtra("TAXI_ID", 0);
            SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBController(this)).getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT bID, bDate, bCombine FROM taxiinfo WHERE bID = ?", new String[]{""+taxiPos});

            if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                bID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttaxibID2);
                bID.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bID")));

                bDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttaxibDate2);
                bDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bDate")));

                bCombine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttaxibCombine2);
                bCombine.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bCombine")));

            }

        }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Booking Details"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.24" />
        <!--  divider -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Ref"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibDate"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Time"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibFrom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="From"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibTo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="To"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibCombine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Combine"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lvcontainer"
        android:layout_weight="6.59"
        android:clickable="false"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtresulttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFF55F54"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"></TextView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvbottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnupload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="UPLOAD"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#1083f5"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnclear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CLEAR"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#1003f5"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnphone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.34"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CALL JDW"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#ffff0000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**v.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffe6e6e6"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
        android:longClickable="false">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibID"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Ref"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibDate"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibTime"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Time"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibFrom"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="From"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttaxibTo"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="To"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**resultstable.xml**

```
<TextLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Booking Details"
            android:textColor="#890000"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
           />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttaxibID2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttaxibDate2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttaxibCombine2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" />

</TextLayout>
```

**csv data for testing**

```
372187,20/09/2015,20:00,Schiphol Taxi Counter Jan de Wit Group,Hotel Lion D'or Golden Tulip,KL1064,Cardiff,Ken Midgley,me@home.com,Ken Midgley,441234567889,41024830,1044889,None,1,
372188,21/09/2015,08:00,Hotel Lion D'or Golden Tulip,3H.18 Dudokhuis Hoofdingang,None,None,Ken Midgley,me@home.com,Ken Midgley,441234567889,41024830,1044889,None,1,Have to be in office by 8:30!!!
372189,21/09/2015,17:30,3H.18 Dudokhuis Hoofdingang,Hotel Lion D'or Golden Tulip,None,None,Ken Midgley,me@home.com,Ken Midgley,441234567889,41024830,1044889,None,1,
372190,22/09/2015,08:00,Hotel Lion D'or Golden Tulip,3H.18 Dudokhuis Hoofdingang,None,None,Ken Midgley,me@home.com,Ken Midgley,441234567889,41024830,1044889,None,2,Mike Smith. Have to be in office by 8:30!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `OnItemClickListener` set on your `ListView`. Here is a simple tutorial how this works - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

After you learn to intercept and handle the event, you can start thinking about navigating to a details activity, or opening a details dialog.

I suggest you go through all of the basic tutorials in http://developer.android.com - all you need is there.

Comment: I have tried and managed to capture the event and place a toast with 6 fields....

What I am trying to do now is open a 2nd view via an intent that I create - not sure if this is what I am supposed to do though.  well I am fairly sure it doesnt work ;)

Comment: Your intent code is wrong. Try using `Intent intent = new Intent(this, TextDetails.class)`. The first parameter is your current activity, the second is the class of the activity you want to reach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately before this revision, I did and I get a red underwiggle on **this**
I copied this from a previous example I used for employee details however this was a ListView not an AdapterView.  Do not know why doesn't work/compile

Comment: It is because you were doing in from inside the OnClickListener. In this case  `this` refers to the listener, and the listener can't be passed as a parameter here. You need to get the enclosing activity instance by using `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Ok that's now at least "compiling" - however there is still something wrong as when I press a record to open the new activity - it just crashes and I get the "Unfortunately, JDW Taxis has stopped" error.  There must be something else at fault.  taking the lines of the OnItemClickListener one by one commented out the one that it fails on is "'            Cursor kursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);'"  it cannot set the adapter - must be using the wrong one ???

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
public void onClickList(final ListView list) {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent,
                                final View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage("youre message");
            final AlertDialog.Builder ok = alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    //add your code here
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Where the list is the ListView object you create. You can send to this method `onClickListener()` your ListView to manage the popup. By the way, you can create your own xml layout to render a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance on the above - I managed now to resolve this issue.

The problem was thinking too hard about passing the position of the click....

The **MainActivity.java** needs the following...

```
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TaxiDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("TAXI_ID", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

The **TaxiDetails.java** then can pick up the extra info in the intent

```
   taxiPos = getIntent().getIntExtra("TAXI_ID", 0);
   taxiPos=taxiPos+1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBController(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM taxiinfo WHERE Id = ?", new String[]{""+taxiPos});

    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
```

Comment: As you can see, this works, but I have to increment the position :(